# Having issue using DOCUMENT_ROOT within php include to set file paths

Tags: php

I have a number of relative file paths within a PHP include.

Historically, I had been setting a $rootPath variable at the top of each page and simply echoing that variable within the file path.

For example:

In the document head:

```
<?php $rootPath = "../">
```

In the include:

```
<img src="<?php echo $rootPath ?>images/file-name.jpg" >
```

The problem is I'm using a hosted CMS platform (Surreal) for this project and their platform can't parse the variable within the include.  Their required syntax uses DOCUMENT_ROOT.

So I switched the code within the include file to:

```
<img src="<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/file-name.jpg'); ?>" >
```

When I do this, none of the content below that line of code is included.

This is on a shared hosting environment, so I may be running into a situation where my document root isn't the web root.

I'm new to this guys.  Take it easy on me.   But if anyone has any suggestions as to what I'm overlooking, I'd be super grateful!

Comment: Use echo instead of include: `<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/images/file-name.jpg" >`

Comment: The DOCUMENT_ROOT is only useful on the server side, for the client application  '/' will represent the root of the website

Answer (score 0):

What do you want?
You don't need use include for images. It will be show bytes, raw data for users in src attribute.

Comment: The img was just an example.  The img is content within a larger include file with links and image paths that need to be relative since the include is used in multiple folder depths.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] doesn't include the ending slash (/) character.  Try this instead:

```
<img src="<?php echo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/file-name.jpg'); ?>" >
```

**EDIT**

In HTML the 'src' attribute can use the slash (/) character to mean the root directory.  In your case that would be '/home/nqtyaxgr/public_html'.  That way the path can be found regardless of page location (any number of sub levels down).

PHP doesn't understand that and that is why you need to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] when you require or include files.  You might/should have a PHP file where all your common constants, variables or functions are located.  I recommend you define a global variable in there also.  It could look like this:

```
$imgPath = "/images/";
```

Then use it in your HTML like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgPath;?>file-name.jpg">
```

Comment: This helps and is getting me closer.  I'm still not getting the path quite right though... likely a result of shared hosting.  The path that's echoing is     src="/home/nqtyaxgr/public_html/images/HERO-estate-on-hill-sq1000.jpg".  This is the correct path, but I need to drop the "home/nqtyzxgr/public_html/" piece.   I know "../" goes up a level.  How do I go down a level?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is good to use when, for example, including or requiring files.  I recommend you set a global variable to use as your image path OR use substring to remove the parts you don't need.